# How to change or delete elements of the form (mostly other dropdowns) depending on a select option?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple forms with different questions and drop downs, and i want to show the correct form depending on the option a user chooses.

So if a user chooses option 1 "Vehicles" he is going to have the form about vehicles (Engine type, brand....),

if he chooses Option 2 "Smartphones" he gonna have a form about smartphones (Chipset, RAM, screen type...)

I wanna do it with vanilla JavaScript, but i'm open to all suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add code that you have tried to get it working or any error you are getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask question so you can get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do something like this in Vanilla JS. But I suggest using some framework such as *AngularJS, React or Angular*. Life will be more easier doing these stuff in any of these.

```js
function selectChange(opt){
 if(opt.value === "1"){
    document.getElementById('smartPhone').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('vehicle').style.display = "block";
 }else if(opt.value === "2"){
   document.getElementById('vehicle').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('smartPhone').style.display = "block"
 }else{
   alert("something");
    document.getElementById('vehicle').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('smartPhone').style.display = "none";
  }
}
function handleSubmit(form){
 alert(form.id)
}
```

```html
<select onchange = "selectChange(this)">
  <option value="1">Vehicle</option>
  <option value="2">SmartPhone</option>
  <option value="3">Something else</option>
</select>

<form id="vehicle" onsubmit="handleSubmit(this)">
    <input type="text" value="vehicle"/>
     <input type="submit" value ="vehicle"/>
</form>
<form id="smartPhone" style="display:none" onsubmit="handleSubmit(this)">
    <input type="text" value="smart phone"/>
    <input type="submit" value ="submit smartphone"/>
</form>
```